# PHP MySQLi is just returning one row in JSON

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on the below code. Why am I getting only one row in my JSON output?

```
$items = [];
if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $items = $row;
     }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
    }
    $this->conn->close();
}
echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: you just missed to indicate that $items is an array with []. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are going through the rows and assigning each of them to `$items`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $items = $row;
}
```

So after the loop is finished you end up with a variable which is a $row that was assigned during the last iteration of that loop.

You would need to push the values to an array like so:

```
$items[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$items[] = $row;` will solve to problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try with array_push function:

```
$items = array();
if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         array_push($items, $row);
     }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
    }
    $this->conn->close();
}
echo json_encode($items);
```

According to [Paolo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino) - What's better to use in PHP `$array[] = $value` or `array_push($array, $value)`?
 He says:

> If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to
>   use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a
>   function.

Answer (score 0):

for solve your problem you must change this part of code:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $items = $row;
}
```

TO:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $items[] = $row;
}
```

But if you use PDO, I think it's better to do that change this part of code:

```
$items = [];
if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $items = $row;
     }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
    }
    $this->conn->close();
}
```

TO:

```
if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

And remove while loop.

Comment: Please explain **why** that change is needed, such that the OP can learn what was wrong

Comment: What do you mean by that? Why don't you want to add some explanation?

Comment: It can be explained in detail, but
i think it's better to go to the blogs for more details,
i said a short comment, clean code
If you do not believe in the clean code we should see what is others opinion.

Comment: To which "blogs" should I go, and what is the relation to clean code? Please keep in mind that people who ask for help on SO are seeking to learn something new. If you don't explain them why your code solves the problem, they cannot learn from your answer and can't write better code in the future

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you only get one row in JSON is because in your `while` loop you overwrite the same variable each time instead of pushing into an array. A simple fix would be to do:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $items[] = $row;
}
```

This can also be written using `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    $items[] = $row;
}
```

You don't need this `while` loop at all. You can make your code much simpler if you use `fetch_all()`. You can simply replace all your code from the question with:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$items = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($items);
```

`fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` will give you all the rows in associative arrays.